localhost social media script, images and avatars not loading
I have installed a script on localhost, script name wowonder. it is a social media, running on php javascript.
I am using wampserver64
The images goes into: wamp64/www/uploads
images not working with inspect
If i use a hosting provider the avatars and images load properly, but when i use localhost the images won't load.
Can anyone help me with this issue
